# How to efficiently convert an 8-bit bitmap to array of 0/1 integers with x86 SIMD

Tags: x86, bit-manipulation, sse, simd, avx2

I want to convert 8 bit integer to an array of size 8 with each value containing the bit value of an integer.

For example: I have `int8_t x = 8;` I want to convert this to `int8_t array_x = {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0};`

This has to be done efficiently, since this calculation is part of signal processing block. Is there a efficient way to do this? I did check the blend the instruction. It didn't suit my requirement when having array elements of size 8-bit. development platform is AMD Ryzen.

Comment: Since the array is is only 64 bits long, I would use the BMI2 `pdep` instruction, or `_pdep_u64`

Comment: See also [How to perform the inverse of _mm256_movemask_epi8 (VPMOVMSKB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21622212/2439725).

Comment: @harold: not a duplicate after all; \@aqrit's nice answer that gets 0/1 with PAND / PMINUB doesn't apply there where you want 0/-1, and is a non-obvious optimization vs. using that and masking.

Answer (score 3):

"Inverse movemask" for a single byte with `0x00:0x01` formatted results, with SIMD but without BMI2.

```
__m128i v = _mm_set1_epi8(bitmap); 
v = _mm_and_si128(v, _mm_set_epi32(0, 0, 0x80402010, 0x08040201));
v = _mm_min_epu8(v, _mm_set1_epi8(1));
_mm_storel_epi64((__m128i*)&array_x[0], v);
```

Comment: if you don't have BMI2 it's better to [do a multiplication technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51750902/995714) instead of a lot of SIMD instructions

Answer (score 2):

The first example at the end of this answer shows how to use the BMI2 instruction `pdep` to compute the 8 byte array.

Note that on Intel Haswell processors and newer, the `pdep` instruction has a throughput of one 
instruction per cycle and a latency of 3 cycles, which is fast. On AMD Ryzen this instruction is 
relatively slow unfortunately: both latency and throughput are 18 cycles.
For AMD Ryzen it is better to replace the `pdep` instruction with a multiplication and a few bitwise operations, which are quite fast on AMD Ryzen, see the second example at the end of this answer.

---

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488675) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21622212)
 for efficient inverse movemask computations, with a scalar source 
and a 256 bit AVX2 vector destination.

Instead of working with 8 bits and 8 bytes at the time, it might be
more efficient to reorganize your algorithm to work with 4 x 8 bits and 4 x 8 bytes per step.
In that case the full AVx2 vector width of 256 bit can be utilized, which might be faster.

Peter Cordes [shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52101074) that the `pext` instruction can be used for the conversion in
the opposite direction: from 8 bytes to 8 bits.

---

Code example with the `pdep` instruction:

```c
/*  gcc -O3 -Wall -m64 -march=skylake bytetoarr.c  */

#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<x86intrin.h>

int main(){

    int i;
    union {
        uint8_t  a8[8];
        uint64_t a64;
    } t;
    /*  With mask = 0b0000000100......0100000001 = 0x0101010101010101    */
    /*  the input bits 0, 1, ..., 7 are expanded                         */
    /*  to the right positions of the uint64_t = 8 x uint8_t output      */
    uint64_t mask = 0x0101010101010101;

    /* example input: */
    uint8_t x = 0b01001100;

    t.a64 = _pdep_u64(x,mask);

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        printf("a[%i] = %hhu\n", i, t.a8[i]);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
$ ./a.out
a[0] = 0
a[1] = 0
a[2] = 1
a[3] = 1
a[4] = 0
a[5] = 0
a[6] = 1
a[7] = 0
```

---

Code example for AMD Ryzen processors:

```c
/*  gcc -O3 -Wall -m64 -march=skylake bytetoarr_amd.c  */

#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<x86intrin.h>

int main(){

    int i;
    union {
        uint8_t  a8[8];
        uint64_t a64;
    } t;

    /* example input: */
    uint8_t  x    = 0b01001100;

    uint64_t x64  = x;                 
    uint64_t x_hi = x64 & 0xFE;                                                  /* Unset the lowest bit.                        */
    uint64_t r_hi = x_hi * 0b10000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000000; /* Copy the remaining 7 bits 7 times.           */
    uint64_t r    = r_hi | x64;                                                  /* Merge the lowest bit into the result.        */
             t.a64= r & 0x0101010101010101   ;                                   /* Mask off the bits at the unwanted positions. */

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        printf("a[%i] = %hhu\n", i, t.a8[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: For future readers, note that `pdep` is not efficient on Ryzen (or Excavator which also has it, I think).  Also, the mask is `0x0101010101010101` if you don't want a huge binary constant in your source.

Comment: I did check pdep instructions. As @PeterCordes mentioned it is very expensive. In Ryzen it has 18 cycles of latency according to agner's manual.

Comment: @yadhu: But on Intel it's very efficient, especially if you want the result in an integer instead of in a SIMD vector.

Comment: @PeterCordes  Sometimes a code becomes more self explaining when you write constants as a binary.
That is not the case here, I admit :-) .